# SVG CSS classes overriding each other in d3

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js, svg

I have a d3 project where SVG "icons" (exported from `Adobe Illustrator`, if that matters) are embedded in a `d3` container. (Project structure is visible in the devtools screen grab below)

A problem has cropped up where the CSS of the last SVG to load overrides the CSS used by prior SVGs. So in the first image below, the styles of "A" and "B" are overridden by the styles in "C"

The classes are defined in `Illustrator` and I don't have any control over them (short of manually editing them in a text editor) and compounding the problem, this is within an `Electron` desktop app which allows the user to add their own icons – so expecting the user to go in an rename the CSS classes is not realistic.

**So my questions:**

1. Is my diagnosis of what is going on correct? (the CSS styles are
       "cascading")
2. Is there a way I can fix this through code, to isolate each SVG?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for all the comments. I only have basic experience using `SVG` and `CSS` but am very comfortable with `Javascript` – so I was wondering if there is some way to "namespace" the `SVG` when I add it to my `d3` container in order to isolate it.

I guess I could parse each SVG using JS and insert unique class names, etc. but there could be 100 or more of these icons in my `d3` container (it's a timeline) – so that approach seems like it would be slow.

---

```html
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 16.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
    <!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
      width="612px" height="792px" viewBox="0 0 612 792" style="enable-background:new 0 0 612 792;" xml:space="preserve">
    <style type="text/css">
    <![CDATA[
     .st0{fill:#DD1431;stroke:#231F20;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
     .st1{fill:#FBB040;}
    ]]>
    </style>
    <circle class="st0" cx="295.989" cy="358.517" r="251.648"/>
    <g>
     <path class="st1" d="M400.258,498.945c-16,8-48,16-89,16c-95,0-166.5-60-166.5-170.5c0-105.5,71.5-177,176-177c42,0,68.5,9,80,15
      l-10.5,35.5c-16.5-8-40-14-68-14c-79,0-131.5,50.5-131.5,139c0,82.5,47.5,135.5,129.5,135.5c26.5,0,53.5-5.5,71-14L400.258,498.945
      z"/>
    </g>
    </svg>
```

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Why do you have `<style>` tag within each `svg`? the rules in the last one will override the previous ones

Comment: Not very clear from your example. Do you use the same classes with different styles? In this case why not changing the selectors you are using

Comment: @enxaneta – the classes are defined and assigned by `Adobe Illustrator` – "untouched by human hands" – I'm just loading the .svg which was exported from AI.

Comment: @ZohirSalak - that's what `Adobe Illustrator` outputs. The top example is a straight dump, not edited after 'save as' from AI as .svg

Comment: But the  "human hands" can change it.

Comment: So you want to isolate each svg using only css ? if you can use javascript this should be easy or am i missing something ?

Comment: write some code to change the class names so they are unique. You could do that via javascript or preprocess things with XSLT or in any number of other ways.

Comment: Maybe save the svg in a file and use it with the `<img>` tag instead

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue! You can avoid it by changing your SVG export presets in Illustrator. When you save the SVG, click `More Options` on the bottom left, then change your CSS Properties to `Presentation Attributes`. (I think the default is `Style Elements`.) Then the SVG code will export without assigning repeating CSS classes.

Got to the solution via [this post](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/how-does-guils-css-override-svg-inline-style).

[image: Illustrator SVG settings -- Presentation Attributes is highlighted in the CSS Properties dropdown]